# exhaustion of $[0,1]/ \Bbb{Q}$ by Jordan sets Ωm

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I tried to prove that $[0,1]/ \Bbb{Q}$ can't be exhausted by jordan sets
all i get is $\Omega = [0,1]/ \Bbb{Q}$ and
∂$\Omega=[0,1]$
I not sure how to continue from here.
thanks ahead

Comment: Wait, $/$ or $\setminus$?

Comment: without the rationals